# Best way to match a substring at the beginning of a string (with some restrictions)

Tags: javascript, string, matching

I have an array of strings:

```
var myArray = ["blue", "yellow", "purple", "bluegreen", "red"];
```

and I need to match one of those elements at the beginning of another string that I'm given. So `"redwood"` should match `"red"`, while `"evergreen"` shouldn't match anything. It needs to be a lazy match, so `"bluegreenskygrass"` should match `"bluegreen"`, not `"blue"`.

I can certainly accomplish this by iterating over every element in the array for every character in the string, but that seems rather computationally expensive. I'm sure there's a better way, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: My guess is it would jut matter on order of `myArray`, making sure `bluegreen` is before `blue` so it matches it first.

Comment: [`String.prototype.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: That also, but that alone, without reordering may not work, cause it for sure match `blue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce`, find matches using `Array#startsWith`, and take the longest match:

```js
var myArray = ["blue", "yellow", "purple", "bluegreen", "red"];

function findMatch(search) {
  return myArray.reduce(function(r, str) {
    return search.startsWith(str) && str > r ? str : r;
  }, '');
}

var result = findMatch('bluegreenskygrass');

console.log(result);
```

If you have a fixed array, and make many searches, you can start by sorting (descending) the array by length, and use `Array#find`. The search will stop as soon as a match is found.

```js
var myArray = ["blue", "yellow", "purple", "bluegreen", "red"];

myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.length - a.length;
});

function findMatch(search) {
  return myArray.find(function(str) {
    return search.startsWith(str);
  });
}

var result = findMatch('bluegreenskygrass');

console.log(result);
```